# Changing Element Class With Javascript Fails When Using Turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, turbolinks

I have the following code *attempting* to toggle a class on the body element:

```
$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {

    // Minimalize menu
    $(document).on('click', '.navbar-minimalize', function (event) {
         $('body').toggleClass('mini-navbar');
    })

    ...
```

It works on a fresh page load every time, but fails EVERY OTHER link navigation thereafter. Fresh page load (class toggle works), 1st link click (broken), 2nd link click (works), etc.

Note that I was using jQuery originally when I spotted the bug, then moved to vanilla JS to see if it was a jQuery issue. Needless to say, it wasn't.

I removed a bunch of other dependencies one by one and the only thing that resolves the issue is by removing Turbolinks and replacing `turbolinks:load` event with jQuery's `document.ready`.

When analyzing with Chrome Dev tools, it shows that the classlist is *trying* to be manipulated (highlights it yellow temporarily), but ultimately nothing changes.

I know this is very strange and probably unique to my codebase. I just can't figure the damn bug out.

-- UPDATE 1 --

Here is the relevant HTML markup. Note the 'a' tag class of 'navbar-minimalize' is the trigger. The body tag is the element which the js is trying to toggle the class.

```
<!-- topnavbar.html.erb -->
<div class="row border-bottom" id="vue-autocomplete-app">

    <nav class="white-bg navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">

        <div class="navbar-header">

            <a class="navbar-minimalize minimalize-styl-2 btn btn-primary" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a>



            <form role="search" class="form form-inline navbar-form-custom" method="" action="">

                <global-search></global-search>

            </form>

        </div>

    </nav>

</div>
```

Then the rails templating code that loads the above template:

```
<!-- application.html.erb -->
<body class="fixed-sidebar">

    <!-- Wrapper-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>

        <!-- Page wraper -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

            <!-- Page wrapper -->
            <%= render 'layouts/topnavbar' %>
...
```

-- UPDATE 2 --

If I move the toggle code outside of the turbolinks:load into a document ready, everything seems to work fine. With that said, it seems to be some sort of quirky behavior with turbolinks.

--

Any help? What's the issue here?

Comment: What does your html look like? I would guess that some work of propagation is happening causing the click function to trigger more than once at a time, but it's hard to say without seeing the bigger picture.

Comment: @RCB added some of the template code. Thanks